# One noun to describe my brothers, sisters and myself

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I am looking for one word to describe my parent's children, in relation to myself. `Siblings` does not cut it in my opinion as I am not part of my siblings. In French there is the word `fratrie` that would qualify, but I could not find any English equivalent.

Post-comments edit/context:

The question arose first in the context of computing (so no 'awkward'  relationship like half-brother) to name a method, hence the 'single word' request because a multi-word description would not work. I then became irked to not find the word I was looking for, specially as there is such a word in French. The question thus goes way beyond computing, I still do not know how to refer about my brothers and myself together in one word.

Comment: What is the sentence or thought you're trying to compose? And do you mean that if you said fratrie in French, people would understand that you have also included yourself in the grouping?

Comment: “My parents’ children” (assuming you have the same set of parents, that is—once you start adding in half-siblings, it gets more complicated).

Comment: The title clearly conflicts with the recent edit. You want a term that you can use in a computer programme, correct? You're not asking about filial relationships, are you?

Comment: 'Siblings' is fine if the speaker is not part of the family.

Comment: "We siblings are going to a movie together."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions related to computer method/variable naming are off-topic.

Comment: @HotLicks I think it is an excellent question. Its purpose may be to resolve a computing issue, but it concerns the English translation of a French word. How does English express the collective of the children of a family. The answer seems to be that in English we cannot, and that is an important discovery.

Comment: @HotLicks The question arose in the context of computing indeed, but not to solve a problem (trivial and obviously off-topic). This is a semantic question, which would be just as valid if I had not given the context, and which itched me enough to want to find an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I will use the term in a program indeed, but this is definitely about filial relationship, and no matter the initial context I got curious about the answer.

Comment: I did ask and vwaited, and when I saw the first votes to close I joined them. If three user vote to reopen I'll join mine. But according to WS2 and to yourself, siblings is not the answer. So... I don't know what anyone could suggest that would satisfy your request.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: 'There is no answer' is a perfectly valid answer, at least I can now stop scratching my brain. :)

Comment: A kindred spirit: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53782/proper-use-of-siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Concise *Hachette* doesn't even give the word, but Collins Cambridge French to English online simply translates it as *brothers and sisters*.

*Toute la fratrie s'est réunie* translates as *All the brothers and sisters are here*.

**So I'm afraid there isn't such a word in English -of that you can be fairly sure.**

Comment: What wrong with saying *All the siblings are here?*

Comment: If you think about it, just like 'brother' or 'sister', 'siblings' is almost always used with reference to a person eg 'my siblings', 'her siblings' which implicitly but necessarily eliminates the referent from consideration. 'My siblings' does not include me. 'Brother' is defined as a male child of my parents ... __who is not me__, 'sibling' similarly. So "All my siblings are home" does not include 'myself'. But if you (or the referent) are not part of that set, then I think 'siblings' works. (but that does not seem to be what the OP is looking for).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Probably nothing at all. But it is not a direct translation of *fratrie* which the OP seems to be seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original point is that one might say "my *fraterie* were all present" (were *fraterie* an English word) with the sense that the speaker is included. But "My siblings were all present" or "My offspring were all present" would not bear this sense, because the speaker is not one of his own siblings or offspring. Could I suggest *cohort*, not a graceful word but a word I did find used with *we* in this quotation (from an online article in Forbes Magazine on Apr 9, 2013 @ 08:08 AM, My Cohort Believes QE Only Benefits the Nation's Wealthiest): "And yes, I got the feeling my cohort last night felt to varying degrees that we could well experience another meltdown..."

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want a term that refers to a singular group rather than individuals, I would suggest something like *fraternity* might be as close as you'll get. It shares the same etymology as *fratrie*, and while it generally means *brotherhood* in the figurative sense and not literal siblings, perhaps it's appropriate here.

Comment: A good word, but this answer would be better if it included a definition and reference.

Comment: In the US "fraternity" is a bunch of drunken college students.

Answer (score -2):

Is **offspring** not the word you are looking for?

[from the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offspring)

> 1. A person's daughter(s) and/or son(s); a person's children
>
> ...
>
> 5. (computing) A process launched by another process
>
> **Usage notes**
>
> - The form offsprings is also used for the plural, especially the computing sense.

Comment: Offspring is in relation to my parents, not to myself. I could use my parent's offspring, but that is not better than my parent's children in my context.

Comment: @Guillaume okay. Then perhaps reconsider **siblings**.  You seem to reject it because "he is my sibling" does not include you. However, "we are siblings" does.

Answer (score -2):

`kins` is the only one in my head that fits your description.

Comment: The way I see it, kins has the same issue as siblings, it does not include self.

Comment: There's no plural for 'kin' as it is a mass noun, right?

Comment: [Kin](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kin) is too broad. It is wider in meaning than "family" which would include your parents, grandparents, spouse, children, grandchildren and, probably, your nieces and nephews. The only answer I can see for the OP is _my siblings and me_ (or I depending on context).

Comment: @Mitch: When I saw the answer using *kins* (with an ***s***), I immediately thought to comment on it — until I saw that you beat me to it (by slightly under a day). But, as *kin* is similar in meaning to *family* (and *clan*), I don’t see why it couldn’t be pluralized in contexts like, “The Smith kin and the Jones kin got together and had a battle of the kins.” OTOH, spell-check doesn’t like *kins*.